# How to load proxy contract's address on implementation contract?

Tags: remix, solidity-0.8.x, proxy-contracts, mocha, smart-contract

[image]

I am learning about Proxy contract . I have been writing contracts in Remix from the day I started learning Solidity .
I will explain my problem statement in some points .

1. CounterV1 is implementation contract here .
2. Proxy is the proxy contract here .
3. Proxy contract has a method upgradeTo() that updates its implementation address . I updated this implementation address to CounterV1's address .
4. Then , after above step I loaded proxy contract's address in the CounterV1's address ( see the button below "Deploy" named "At Address )" .

After all this , the proxy contract works correctly as intended .
Now the problem I am facing is when I write tests for Proxy contract using Mocha , how can I load address of Proxy contract in CounterV1 ( implementation contract ) ( see point number 4 ) .

I am pasting CounterV1 and Proxy Contract's code below :

```
contract CounterV1 { //first implementation contract

    uint256 public count; 

    event INCREMENT(uint256);

    function inc() external {
        count = count + 1 ;
        emit INCREMENT(count);
    }
    
    function getCount() external view returns(uint256) {
        return count;

    }
        
    function admin() external pure returns(address) {
        return address(1);
    }

    function implementation() external pure returns(address) {
        return address(2);
    }

}
```

Below is Library StorageSlot and Proxy :

```
library StorageSlot { //library used to store address of admin contract and implementation contract 

    struct AddressSlot { // why this inside struct ?
        address value;
    }

    function getAddressSlot(bytes32 slot) internal pure returns (AddressSlot storage r) {
        assembly {
            r.slot := slot // pointer ??
        }
    }
}
contract Proxy { // Proxy contract 

    // slots to prevent collision ( idk what it actually means ) 
    bytes32 public constant IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT = bytes32(          // slot for implementation contract ( this slot stores address of implementation contract ) 
        uint(keccak256("eip1967.proxy.implementation")) - 1
    ); 
    
    bytes32 public constant ADMIN_SLOT = bytes32(                   // slot for admin contract ( this slot stores address of admin contract ) 
        uint(keccak256("eip1967.proxy.admin")) - 1
    );

    constructor() {
        _setAdmin(msg.sender);
    } 

    function _delegate(address _implementation) private {

        assembly { // since _delegate function cannot return anything , this code inside assembly { } will help us to return data we want .

            calldatacopy(0, 0, calldatasize())

            let result := delegatecall(gas(), _implementation, 0 , calldatasize(), 0, 0)
        
            returndatacopy(0,0,returndatasize())
            
            switch result
            
            case 0 {
                revert(0,returndatasize())
            }
            default {
                return(0,returndatasize())
            }
        }
    }

    function _fallback() private {  
        _delegate(_getImplementation());
    }

    //fallback() is triggered when msg.data is not empty
    fallback() external payable { // calling all other functions using fallback() method
        _fallback();
    }

    //receive() is triggered when msg.data is empty
    receive() external payable {
        _fallback();
    }
    
    modifier ifAdmin() {
        if(msg.sender == _getAdmin()) {
            _;
        } else {
            _fallback();
        }
    }

    function changeAdmin(address _admin) external ifAdmin{ // change admin of proxy contract
        _setAdmin(_admin);
    }

    function upgradeTo(address _implementation) external ifAdmin{ // upgrade implementation of proxy contract 
        
        _setImplementation(_implementation);
    } 

    function _getAdmin() private view returns(address) { // private getter function to get Admin address of proxy contract 
        return StorageSlot.getAddressSlot(ADMIN_SLOT).value;
    }
    
    function _setAdmin(address _admin) private { // private setter function to set Admin address of proxy contract 
        require(_admin != address(0),"zero address");
        StorageSlot.getAddressSlot(ADMIN_SLOT).value = _admin;
    } 

    function _getImplementation() private view returns(address) { // private getter function to get Implementation contract address of proxy contract 
        return StorageSlot.getAddressSlot(IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT).value;
    }
    
    function _setImplementation(address _implementation) private { // private setter function to set Implementation contract address of proxy contract 
        require(_implementation.code.length > 0 ,"not a contract");
        StorageSlot.getAddressSlot(IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT).value = _implementation;
    }

    function admin() external view returns(address){ // current Admin address
        return _getAdmin();
    }

    function implementation() external view returns(address){ // current Implementation contract address
        return _getImplementation();
    }

}
```